# pandas groupby with nan

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following df:

```
Index |  label  | X1 | X2 
 0    |    H    | 50 | nan   
 1    |    H    | 150| nan   
 2    |    Y    | 150| 20    
 3    |    Y    | 200| nan
```

I want to groupby df based on label and sum the results on X1 and X2. The only caveat is that I want to make sure that if all of the values for a label is nan the final output has to be nan.

Desired results

```
 Index |  label | X1  | X2 
 0     |   H    | 200 | nan   
 1     |   Y    | 350 | 20
```

df.groupby(['label']).sum() does not provide this output that is not desirable

```
 Index |  label | X1  | X2 
 0     |   H    | 200 | 0   
 1     |   Y    | 350 | 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `min_count=1` parameter to [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

> min_count int, default 0

> The required number of valid values to perform the operation. If fewer than min_count non-NA values are present the result will be NA.

```
df1 = df.groupby('label', as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
print (df1)
  label   X1    X2
0     H  200   NaN
1     Y  350  20.0
```